# Create UIView overlay to capture all touches and gestures

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have a view hierarchy that includes a top-level UIView with a nested UIScrollView that contains numerous nested UIViews containing UILabels, UITextFields etc.

I'd like to overlay a UIView over the top of everything so I can intercept certain touch and drag events (basically for editing the overall layout).

I'd like the UIScrollView to still work, so I need to pass (all?) touches and gestures through the overlay to the underlaying views.  When certain touches occur I will intercept the touch and create a dragging situation where the touched subview will be programmatically moved around within the subviews.

What is the best way to create the overlay UIView so that (all?) touches and gestures can be passed through?  Some code examples would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I revised my structure so the overlay handled everything using pan gestures

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the overlay UIView and override the touchesBegan, touches.. methods like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Do your stuff
    [[[self view] nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Do the same for touchesMoved, touchesEnded and touchesCancelled.

Not 100% sure this will work, give it a go :)

Comment: This does not work. I believe it passes the touch through to the 'base' or 'root' UIView, bypassing all the UIViews sitting on top of the base.  This is presumably because the overlay is actually a direct subview of the base, not of all the other views sitting in between.